# How to validate an Image extension with Express Validator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-validator

Good nigth to  everyone. Im just finishing my first course to start programming and Im having lot of problems to validate an image extension using express-validator.

I need to validate an image to be "PNG", "JPEG", "JPG", or "GIF". I tried a few things but nothing worked. Some advice will be great for me, thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

The `validator` package would be more adaptable for this stuff, you can use `isIn` for this

```
req.checkBody( "your extension" ).isIn([ "PNG", "JPEG", "GIF" ]);
```